# What is an effective way to level smithing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Leveling smithing to 100 seems like a difficult task. Is it more effective to craft cheap things such as iron daggers, or to craft expensive items such as Elven weapons?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Value Matters now. It used to take about 400 iron daggers to level up to 100. Now it takes about 2400 iron daggers.

From UESP: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling

- 25 + (3 * [item value]^0.65) base XP for constructing an item.
- 25 + (8 * [item value delta]^0.6) base XP for improving an item.

So, making more expensive things and adding more value is a good thing. But making something twice as expensive does not give you twice as much experience.

### Early Stage

First, try to stack as many XP boosts as possible. Make sure you activate the [Warrior's Stone](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Guardian_Stones) for a 20% XP boost, and get [a good night's sleep](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Well_Rested) for a 5% - 15% XP boost. If you're further along in the game, [completing a certain quest](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unfathomable_Depths) will add another 15% bonus to your Smithing XP gain.

Making iron daggers and leather bracers is still good way of leveling up in early stages. It's quite useful when your level is low.

Jewelry is another good way to level up in early stages. You can obtain large amounts of gold and silver ingots by buying or mining iron ores, which are cheap and plentiful, and turn them into silver and gold ores with the [Transmute Mineral Ore](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Transmute#Transmute) spell. Don't sell the gemstones you get from mining and adventuring; use them to craft even more valuable jewelry.

Training is very inexpensive under Level 50, especially if you sell off all that jewelry you're crafting.

### Mid Level

[Dwarven Smithing](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dwarven_Smithing#Dwarven_Smithing) (Level 30): Useful if you're going up the right side of the tree. Dwarven ingots are plentiful in this game. You can get scrap metals from Dwemer ruins and turn them into dwarven ingots. If you have Dwarven perk on the right side of the Smithing tree, you can take advantage of this. Once you reach Level 30 in Smithing, you can start making Dwarven Bows (2 dwarven ingots + 1 iron ingot) and upgrade (1 dwarven ingot).

[Advanced Armors](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Advanced_Armors) (Level 50): Useful if you are going up the left side of the tree. With this perk, you can start making Steel Plate Armor. It has the highest value added ratio, so very likely you will make profit even if you buy Steel and Corundum ingots, make Steel Plate Armor, upgrade it, and sell it back to the blacksmith. Speech skill and being able to get good deals is somewhat important for this strategy.

### High Level

Upgrading an expensive armor adds a lot of value as your level gets high in smithing. You increase the value by 50% for upgrading to Exquisite (Level 40 with perk). You double the value if you upgrade the armor to legendary. This effect is amplified if you use Fortify Smithing enchanted gear and have Fortify Smithing potions.

One way you can take advantage of your high smithing level is to buy expensive armors and weapons at the blacksmith, upgrading them, and selling them back. If you have items that enhance prices (Volsung, Masque of Clavicus, Necklace of Haggling, Potion of Fortify Barter), you can make profit doing this.

Comment: Looks good, but it might be helpful to add a note about Transmute Metal Ores - it's an easy way to get a bunch of gold and silver ore, which can be turned into high value jewelry (especially with gems, as you suggest). If you add something about that (and also the usual recommendations about activating the Warrior's Stone) I'll give you the bounty :)

Comment: I mined and bought every iron ore I could find and saved them up for transmute.  I then crafted some really good fortify alteration equipment and transmuted like a mofo, refilling my magika with potions.  I had like 60 gold ingots and pumped out expensive gold jewelry like a champ.  Got my smithing up real good that way.

Comment: if the formula is correct then you missed a couple things: the more ingots the item cost the more it reduces the ingot / exp correlation which is what you need for leveling here: http://bit.ly/V1esGU. So for example at low levels arrows gives 24 per ingot vs dagger only 10, so if your formula is correct arrows are the best at all levels.

Comment: Additions I might add are Prowler's Profit, The Forgemaster's Fingers, Silver-Blood Family Ring, and The Lover Stone (via Aetherial Crown). Then, we're cook-smelting with gas-metaphorical-magic!

Comment: What is this certain quest?

Comment: Oh okay I did a quest when you return a lexicon and I got an effect which increase blacksmithing. I made lots of gold rings which helped me a lot.

Comment: Just for evidence sake: [Graph crafting vs upgrading](http://tinyurl.com/hjvyqve)

Comment: I estimated the rarity of different materials (from the Whiterun blacksmith, where you can buy materials both inside and outside). Based on this, to maximise your XP while still making a profit and using all available materials, you'll want to make and then improve, from highest priority to lowest: Nordic Mace, Orcish Helmet, Steel Plate Armor, Ebony Bow, Dwarven Bow, Iron Dagger (you make a slight loss on the last two). Also buy and transmute iron ore to make gold rings. Not all will be available depending on your perks, but you can use this as a guide. I got to 100 and rich very quickly.

Answer (score 23):

Outdated:

To quickly level smithing, you should primarily focus on leather bracers and iron daggers, due to the fact these are two of the cheapest items to smith, and can be sold to cover any expenses.

The materials required, iron and leather, are fairly cheap and are easy to find. If you have a nice lump of cash, it is more effective to use this method and ignore making armor for your level. The reason for this is that you will be quickly leveling, allowing for constant improvement, as well as an increase in the effectiveness in upgrades (ranging from Fine to Legendary).

New:

In the recent patches of Skyrim, it is more efficient to focus on more expensive equipment to level smithing. While it may not cheap, crafting higher level equipment is definitely more cost efficient. While I'm unsure of the exact values, try finding a balance between mining trips and buying ores in order to keep up with smithing production.

Comment: just to add to this, before selling the daggers and bracers back, [enchant them with a weak enchantment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36017/efficent-enchantment-skill-up/36021#36021) to get some skill experience in that at the same time.  Also this boosts the money you gain anyway.

Comment: Additionally, if you're on the PC version, moving the mouse fractionally left and right over the "Yes" button on the "Do you want to craft this item?" dialogue box allows you to craft as fast as you can alternate between left-clicking and pressing R (to craft the selected item). If you keep it in the same place, you seem to have to wait for a second before it highlights "Yes", allowing you can craft the subsequent item.

Comment: Also, if you improve the dagger/item it counts at smith and separates them so that they sell as a single item, not stacked. You can also enchant them, making this a 3 skill leveling opportunity.

Comment: The new patch is going to make this advice obsolete, as skill gain will depend on created item price.

Comment: @kotekzot It did :( Now leveling Smithing like this is pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 9):

I'm currently level 100 smithing, I found that doing steel daggers, iron daggers, and leather bracers the most effective way. Also, buy and smith in whiterun, fast travel to riverwood then buy and smith there, then go back to whiterun, wait ~48 hours, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Almost exact same way I achieved 100 :p

Answer (score 6):

There is a Dwarven Storehouse in Eastern Skyrim.  Go there, along with it's nearby major quest dungeon, and note that there is about 2000lbs of dwemer 'stuff' between them.  A lot of it is behind Expert locked doors, but also a ton in side areas around boss fights.  Pick up everything excepting the Bowls, which apparently Dwarves had a major thing for...  Even if you just do the storehouse it's enough for you and follower full upgraded dwarven set.

-- sploit --
Your mule, er... follower...  can hold an unlimited quantity of loot if you drop it on the ground when you become encumbered and use the manual commands to have him/her pick things up.  Pick it up yourself, then find an empty big area with a clean floor to drop things in, as it's around a 10ft circle of loot in all directions.  NOTE: most items don't stack: but ingots and some other items do.  This means if you drop 20 ingots from your personal inventory on to the ground, then have your follower pick it up, they only get ONE.  Drop each one using single quantity to workaround, or just keep ingots and drop all the other stuff.

Smelted, it totaled 360 ingots for me.  Made Dwarven Bows (only need 1 iron ingot in addition), improved to Epic, and then enchanted with Common/Petty Paralysis.  Get near 500 gold each with crap 30 speech skill, and have so many in house chest I could spend rest of game selling the vendors out of cash.  If you aren't high enough from iron daggers to make the bows, just sell ingots to pay for iron/leather until you can.

Comment: Instead of dumping on the floor (which I think is more likely to disappear after time passes) you can stash all the items in any container, like a chest.  Great advice, I am going to take a horse there and then carry everything at once.  The walking will be slow, but once I reach the horse I can fast-travel home.

Answer (score 6):

As of the newest patch, Smithing skill gains are now linked to the value of the item crafted. This means Leather Bracers and Iron Daggers are no longer the order of the day as soon as you can make something better.

Comment: With the patch/value change, the two tactics that I found seemed to work well were crafting Steel Plate (if you've gone up the light/advanced armors side) and/or grabbing the Transmute spellbook to turn iron ore into gold ore and then crafting jewelry. The latter works particularly well if you have the perk that greatly increases your chances of finding gems in world containers (can't think of what it's called just now), because you can then easily create very high value jewelry.

Comment: @nezroy You should flesh that out into an answer for some delicious bounty!

Answer (score 4):

Iron daggers and leather bracers are probably the best things to craft (I tried upgrading a lot of forsworn armor, but you don't seem to get as good of gains from upgrading as you do crafting new items), but a couple of other things will help you as well.

Use the warrior stone SW of Riverwood to get the extra 20% gains to combat skills (smithing counts as a combat skill) and try to smith while well rested for additional gains.  You can't get the well rested bonus if you have lycanthropy, but the combat stone helps a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Buy the materials to craft Steel Chests and the Plate Chest when you unlock them, then refine them with bought Condorium and sell back to a vender. Wait a couple days or change smithing spots, and you will have a unending supply of money and smith materials.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some scientifically gathered data about the cumulative number of craftings required to attain a given skill level.  (p) indicates that a number was projected/calculated, and not actually measured.

```
Item            level  30,  40,  50,  60,      70;      100
Iron Dagger           147, 303, 488, 725,    1024; (p) 2378
Iron Armor             65, 124, 199, 296, (p) 418; (p)  971
Gold Diamond Necklace  19,  36,  58,  86,     121;      281
```

It takes fewer craftings to reach the cap for value-able items.  That was the goal of the change, so well done Bethesda.  If you are limited by time at the forge, make the most expensive thing you can.

---

Here are the cumulative number of iron bars used.  As you can see, Iron Armor leveling requires approximately twice the Iron Bars compared to Iron Dagger leveling

```
Item            level  30,  40,  50,  60,        70;      100
Iron Dagger           147, 303, 488,  725,     1024; (p) 2378
Iron Armor            325, 620, 995, 1480, (p) 2090; (p) 4855
```

If you are limited by access to materials, stick to making cheap items.

---

I attempted to verify leveling via upgrades, but the UI is unfavorable toward performing hundreds of upgrades.  However I don't think the UESP formula is correct - [previous research](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57279/how-does-value-affect-the-gain-of-smithing-experience/57451#57451) (384 xp = iron dagger x10, 171 xp = upgrade x10 @ skill 84).  The formula predicts that I should get more than 25 xp, but I got 17.1 xp.

---

@Jagd

Ebony dagger takes 1 bar for 290 value.

Ebony bow takes 3 bars for 1440 value.

Ebony armor takes 5 bars for 1500 value, inferior to Ebony Bow.

You can craft 6 daggers or 2 bows.

(290^0.65)*3 + 25 = 144.  144*6 = 864  <-- daggers win.
(1440^0.65)*3 + 25 = 363.  363*2 = 726

Comment: These tests were starting from 15 skill with no bonuses.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard that Iron Daggers are the best way to level smithing.

Go to Whiterun, buy your iron ingots and leather/leather strips, wait 24/48 hours (I think it's 24), then buy more and repeat if you have the cash and build up a stock to save you having to return to the shop as often. Then, sell all of your iron daggers and repeat.

I'm guessing you want the Dragon Armour. I'm after the same thing, so good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a lot of iron daggers then enchant them.  Then you can also make money, and increase your Enchantment skill.

Answer (score 0):

Fast travel around to all of the blacksmiths and buy all of the iron ore, iron ingots and leather strips you can. Go back to Whiterun to make them and sell them. Why Whiterun, because Whiterun has everything you need, even a smelter and there are five people who will buy iron daggers with one open at night not counting your spouse if you have one. Wash, Rinse, Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

When I played Skyrim, the way I used was just buying a ton of leather and iron from the blacksmith place in Whiterun and make a lot of Iron Daggers, it worked pretty well until your level gets about 40ish. Then the leveling started to get pretty slow so it's better if you save up a lot of money beforehand for buying the supplies. It takes longer than you think...
Plus the stocks of iron and leather go up again every 24 hours or so.
You're probably leveling for the dragon or daedric armor, good luck with that, hope you succeed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Iron armor and leather helmets are actually the most cost effective investments at low level. A ratio of around 2,5 gold/gold spent.

That means if you have enough fortify barter (blackguard hood+amulet of zenithar.)
You will be able to endlessly craft without losing any gold. Traveling from one town to the next.

And if you are a vampire you can even wear Volsung with the blackguard hood.