# Efficent Enchantment Skill-up

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What is the most cost-effective way to increase enchantment? it seems too expensive to buy materials from vendors, and finding soul gems that have souls in them takes a while.

Comment: Soul trap some foxes and wolves into petty gems. I have like 70 empty petty gems in my inventory because I keep forgetting to soul trap.

Comment: The quickest I see is using a soul tap weapon. Stock up on petty gems and the assortment and kill a bunch of things. Then, use smithing to create a variety of rings and enchant them. This was fairly cheap for myself, especially after finding a gold mine.

Comment: @desaivv Ore makes Ingots.  Ingots are what is used to make final products - including rings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are all the ways to gain experience for [enchanting](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Enchanting_(Skyrim)):

- Disenchanting items
- Enchanting items
- Using Soulgems to recharge weapons (Soul Siphon does not count)

Personally the method I use is the one suggested in the wiki, which is to craft iron daggers, and then using petty soulgems to enchant them with a low level enchantment, and selling the daggers back to the shopkeeper.

This allows you to improve three skills at the same time: smithing, enchanting, and speech.  The amount you make selling the enchanted items offsets the cost of buying the materials.

Just grab/buy every low level soulgem you come across and you'll level up enchanting in no time.  Having a soul trap weapon will make this process much easier.

Comment: Isn't enchanting XP tied to the level of enchantment you apply?  If so, why not use Banish instead of "a low level enchantment".

Comment: nope, its per attempt

Comment: Well, I'd still use Banish - just for the mountain-loads of easy gold it generates.

Comment: yes that's true.  If you have banish, definitely use it for the money.

Comment: And if you don't have it, pop it.  Even if just that means constantly checking shop inventories and waiting two days in between, it's well worth the time.

Comment: If you have conjuration, you can use bound weapons to perform the soul trap if you have the perk, also.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to find a weapon that has the ability to trap souls inside of soul gems - I disenchanted it to learn the ability, and applied the enchantment to my primary weapon. Now I just have to carry around soul gems and kill things as I normally would; they get filled automatically.

You should also note that while soul gems can be expensive, you can enchant trinkets that you find during your dungeon-crawling and sell those for an inflated profit.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to get conjuration up and find the school of conjuration and soul trap higher level Conjurations.

I think the best bet is to Start with the Dark Brotherhood, if you do the Bonus's you will receive stuff that will aid you and in the end you get 20000 Gold which you could use to aid you in buying the equipment.

Comment: You can't soul trap your own summons in Skyrim.

Comment: I have an enchanted weapon that will allow me to soul trap my conjurations. Got it from a shrine.

Answer (score 1):

Buy the spell:[soul trap](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Soul_Trap)  and fill the empty gems yourself. Can be bought at the nearest spell book seller.

Answer (score 0):

This is my method for an easy way to gain money and up your enchanting:

You will need to have a house and wife. This is the easy way to gain money because your wife will pay you for waiting. You will want about 5000 to 8000 gold for purchasing soul gems; I chose a house in Whiterun(cost of the house is 5000). I believe you can get that house fairly easily. I chose [Aeri](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Aeri) as my wife for the simple fact that I just had to have the amulet of mara and do one task for her to marry me.

Now  what you want to do is go to Riften and enter the blacksmith's house. Go downstairs and steal his iron engots and ore and leather and strips; this is cost effective because it costs you nothing. Solitude's blacksmith is the next guy you want to go rob and if your speech is at 100 with all perks you can rob them blind and then sell what you don't want back to them.

Now make iron daggers; again, I'm in Whiterun, so I used the forge next to my house but any forge will do. Once you have between 30 and 40 daggers, store them at your house. Keep in mind to do this you have to have disenchanted a weapon...a weapon with fire is good for this method. Now go to Dragonreach and [find Farengar](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Farengar_Secret-Fire). Buy any soul gem from him that costs 100 or less.

Now this is where your wife comes into play; wait 3 days and buy more and so on and so on etc.

Once you have the soul gems use ether soul trap or a weapon with soul trap on it and kill animals until all your soul gems are full. Once you have that done, go to your wife and she will have money waiting for you. Get your daggers and then enchant them, since enchanting them ups your enchantment skill. Sell them to make your money back and repeat  until you are satisfied with your enchanting.

This is based off of the Xbox 360 version of the game. 
By the way, after waiting 3 to 4 days the blacksmiths mentioned will regenerate what you stole. I also find when going out to trap souls, follow rivers; mud crabs and deer are all over the place around rivers. Also, smithing iron daggers ups your smithing fast and soul trap casted over and over on an enemy like a mud crab ups your conjuration fast.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get my soul-gems easily and free oh yeah and fast. There's a chest in dawnstar by Ironvbreaker mine its left of the mine in the rocks. It has a lot of other stuff too. To refill it there's a khajiit merchant by the entrance of Dawnstar If they arent there wait a while. The one sitting in the tent save looking at her. Then kill or harm her. Load the save. And now after the load talk to the Khajit and look through the stuff. Exit your chat with her and the stuffs back.