# What is the fastest way to level up as an Enchanter?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficent Enchantment Skill-up](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36017/efficent-enchantment-skill-up)

Should I just enchant everything I come across, no matter how weak it might be? 
I noticed recharging weapons/staffs helps too, but its kind of hard when I forget what I disenchanted. 
EDIT: What I mean by forgetting what I disenchanted, I bring all my crap after an adventure to the enchantment table and pretty much everything either can't be disenchanted or already has. It would be nice to have a list like spells known, while out adventuring so if I saw something, I would know I needed it.

Comment: The lack of a list of known enchantments is just one of skyrims many ui failures. I understand dumbing down an interface for the console people and their controllers, but that's no excuse for not providing a decent separate one for pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest/cheapest/fastest way to level enchanting is to enchant `IRON DAGGERS` & `HIDE BRACERS`

- Buy ALL the iron ingots & all leather & strips the smith has EACH time you visit after the 2 day rest/wait.
- Make iron daggers & hide bracers.
  `DAGGERS` = 1 iron ingot & 1 leather strip.
  `HIDE BRACERS` = 2 leather strips & 1 leather.
- Sell ALL bracers you make back to the smith but SAVE ALL IRON DAGGERS & drop them off at your enchanting table for later.
- When you're ready at your enchanting table, select your daggers, then select, say, fire damage, then select it again for the highest amount of charges. The amount it shows is your
  maximum potential at your current levels/perks. (I use fire damage because they sell well.)
- Select your soul gem, use from lowest to highest. There's no need to use anything higher than common. You DO NOT get more leveling credit for using higher gems like a black or grand. You get the same credit regardless.
- Collect all the lowest level gems you can, bind souls to them, then rinse and repeat the above.

Comment: What is a hide bracer? What it has to do with enchanting?

Comment: @ Master69Wraith - Thanks! That sounds like a great idea. Why not enchant the bracers though?

Comment: @ Jitamaro - Bracers are a piece of armor that covers your forearms, where as gauntlets are like gloves, but also protect your forearms.

Comment: The part about hide bracers has nothing to do with your enchanting advice.

Comment: Also the caps aren't necessary.

Comment: In fact this doesn't answer the question much, if at all. The problem with levelling enchanting is not finding things to enchant, it's having enough soul gems.

Comment: It does help in that daggers are cheap and light, but you are correct in that a ton of gems are required. If you take smithing for example though, my experience will go a lot higher for a set of plate mail vs a dagger itself.

Comment: you can enchant the bracers too but they sell badly,and since your upping smithing making the daggers and the hide bracers take leather/strips so easy way to up both skills otherwise you also have to buy or chase down daggers,also gives you an item to sell to help make back a little money,i did this in Solitude where i had access to 2 mannnies in my house and would constantly buy the gems below the smith and fill them in the swamps fast traveling to the abandoned shack-blue palace : )  yousmith/sell/buygems/enchant/sell rinse and repeat don't see how that's hard but i'll say sorry anyway.sorry