# Does it matter what item I enchant?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to grind to 100 Enchanting skill. Will enchanting an item heavier than an **Iron Dagger** net more experience?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficent Enchantment Skill-up](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36017/efficent-enchantment-skill-up)

Comment: @Wipqozn While this is similar, the other question is asking what's the most efficient, while this is just asking specifically if you get more experience for enchanting something that's heavier.

Answer (score 6):

No it does not.

It doesn't matter what you enchant, it only matters how many things you enchant, and the level of the enchantment (dictated by the size of the soul used).

The fastest way to level enchanting is to get as many iron daggers as you can, and enchant them with your most expensive enchantment with petty souls (or higher if you run out, but use the lowest level ones possible).

As a side effect you'll also make a lot of money selling the daggers.

Comment: I'll just add that the most valuable enchantment is Paralyze.

Comment: @AlexandarŽivkovič Are you sure? I'm fairly certain Banish is the most valuable.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I mistook it with Alchemy. You're right, it's Banish.

Comment: @Dragonord If this answer helped you, consider marking it as correct (the little tick under the arrows to the left), if you think it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it really doesn't matter what item you enchant and it doesn't matter what kind of soul gem you use to do it, you still get the same amount of progress towards leveling your enchanting skill. I really recommend getting gold ingots and smithing as many gold rings as you can, they will be plentiful since you get 2 per ingot. As an added bonus they will sell for quite a lot more than the Iron Daggers.

Comment: Also, if you have the Transmute spell, you can transmute the iron into gold. That way you don't have to go looking for gold and you can level up your Alteration magic.