# Would it be better to make daggers, or do training from blacksmiths

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Currently, my smithing level is 71. There are only two options of increasing smithing for me:

- Making Iron Daggers
- Get Training From Smithing Experts

Which method is more faster and can help me reach 100 Smithing?

Comment: "i have tried the 500 daggers but found out that they patched it" - what does this even mean?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer the only thing I can think of is the way of leveling up black smithing by becoming a iron dagger blacksmith. But this quest is extremely badly worded and confusing.

Comment: Your question is unclear, as it's making a lot of unwritten assumptions.  Please consider expanding your post.

Comment: The well rested bonus does give extra exp when training skills, but as a werewolf you can't get that bonus, so that whole part of the question is irrelevant. So that basically leaves "What's the best way to increase your smithing level", which is already answered [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35541/145980). If that doesn't answer your question, you need to spend some time to write your question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

For quite some time now, leveling smithing in Skyrim has been linked to the monetary value that you create.  As an Iron Dagger is worth little more than it's materials, it's a lousy way to grind smithing.

Without perks: Turn every gem you loot in to jewelery.  Heck, do this even if you *are* buying smithing perks.  The `Transmute` spell is valuable here for making use of relatively cheap Iron Ore.  Nothing adds value to Iron Ore like turning it into a Gold Diamond Necklace.

With perks:  Look to the item you can produce in each category with the best profit over it's material costs.  For example, with the Dwarven Perk you can turn all of that remarkably common dwemer metal into Dwarven bows.  Also be aware that Grindstone/Armorer's Table improvements are very valuable here also.