# What is the best way to level archery?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an effective way to level Archery?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36508/what-is-an-effective-way-to-level-archery)

In Skyrim I love nothing more than to send an arrow flying through my opponents head and watching them die in slow motion. But how would I level archery in a faster and more efficient way? I use my bow all the time in combat but the progress is still terribly slow. Are there any more efficient and faster ways to level archery other than going to a trainer?

Comment: i don't know of any better ways of leveling it than shooting stuff and going to a trainer I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say leveling the bow works in the same way as leveling any weapons. So it uses the amount of damage you deal to determine the xp gain.

So you could try to find yourself a very strong enemy and find a location from where you can attack but can't be attacked. And then just shoot at the target.

Also you can use one of the standing stones (I guess thief) to increase the xp rate. And the well slept bonus.

Btw. I would suggest you use the trainers for early and mid levels and books for the later levels, since the higher levels cost very much gold.