# Prevent Lydia from 'protecting' the enemy from your arrows

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way (or mod even) to prevent Lydia from trying her hardest to get between you and your target when using bows?   It's an absolute pain in the ass.  I often have to tell her to wait behind if I need to clear a room.

Comment: There is no XP in Skyrim. You raise your skills by using them. So yes, technically you are missing that little raise maybe, but it is not big of a deal if you did the most "work".

Comment: I was using 'XP' as a general term for points gained or skill gained.  I've edited the question.  Anyway thanks for the comment.  I was wondering if there was a points boost for getting the kill.  Some games have that.  I think fallout did it but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your second question is answered here: [What is an effective way to level Archery?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36508/4797)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mod, **[SkyTweak](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/33395/?)** could help. Try tweaking the  ff.variables in the 'NPC' section: 'Follower Spacing' and 'Follower Catch Up'. This should make your followers keep their distance from you.

[image]

Follower Spacing: How closely a follower will try to follow you.
Follower Catch Up: Speed bonus provided to followers when they are far away from the player character.

The tweaks won't stop the follower from entering a fight, but will make them increase their distance from you. This makes them less likely to get in the way between you and an enemy you're fighting. AFAIK, there is no way to completely tweak a follower's behavior / AI to make them get out of your line of sight when you're fighting an enemy.

Comment: As I'm reading the question, this doesn't answer it. He wants to know how to stop the follower from being between him and his target, not how to prevent them from entering the fight.

Comment: @Ender The tweaks won't stop the follower from entering a fight, but will make them increase their distance from you, making them less likely to get in the way between you and an enemy you're fighting.

Comment: Thanks galacticninja.  I might give this a try and see if it has a positive effect.   Alternatively I could persivere until my Archery skill is so high that I can one-shot everything, not giving Lydia a chance to have a go.