# What is the best way of leveling restoration?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There are some nice restoration perks I'm trying to level up for.

Does (dual) casting heal when your health is full gain restoration experience?

If not, what are some good restoration leveling techniques?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Skills only level when the game judges them to have been "usefully" employed; in the case of spells, that means the spell must have had some noticeable effect. Casting healing spells at full health does nothing, nor does casting damage spells into a wall or armor spells without entering combat.

For leveling restoration, your best bet is to use the turn undead spell line, which gives skill increases very quickly. Head to your favorite barrow and start sending the skeletons fleeing before you kill them.

I would strongly caution against "boosting" non-damage skills in Skyrim. You risk your character leveling up too rapidly without having the combat skills he needs to survive. These techniques are best employed to catch up support skills that have fallen behind.

Comment: I imagine you could even turn your own conjured skeletons, if you don't have a barrow handy.

Answer (score 13):

There are actually many techniques to leveling restoration in Skyrim. I found myself needing to do this in order to balance my character better; I had completed the main quest line so was merely playing for the hell of it.

**How it works**

The trick for leveling spell-based skills is to cast the spell so that it will have some affect or rather: change the environment/game.

In the case of restoration spells and therefore leveling it, you'll need to cast a restoration spell -- [Healing](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Healing), [Fast Healing](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Fast_Healing), [Close Wounds](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Close_Wounds) for instance -- so that it gives you health. Casting on a full health bar won't give you experience.

To summarise: the general idea is to take some damage and then cast a restoration spell.

**Leveling restoration by spells alone**

So, one way in which to harm yourself so you can heal straight away; and do so in a controlled manner, is to cast the alteration spell [Equilibrium](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Equilibrium) -- which converts health to magicka for the duration of the cast, but can kill you -- and then heal once your health is low enough for the restoration spell to apply.

I personally found this a little slow so opted for the slightly modified method below.

**Taking constant damage**

An alternative method is to stand on a device or area that will harm you constantly, such as a under a fire trap or [as
in this example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pt9AHVFRTpE) the wind at the top of High Hrothgar that leads to the Throat of the World. In the latter case
(*slight-spoiler alert!*) you just have to walk towards the winds to stumble and take damage, at which point you can dual-wield a restoration spell and cast as soon as your health gets too low.

You could also find a pack of wolves, a bear (if you can take the damage), spiders or other pack-based enemies and not attack but dual-wield your restoration spell so you don't die. This saves on having to cast two spells and has the added benefit of leveling armor and such skills. Do bear in mind though, that leveling multiple skills like this will yield your overall level increasing which could mean you'll end up fighting mobs that are too high for your combat skills.

As I said above, I opted for the winds at High Hrotgar as you only need to concentrate on casting the restoration spell and the damage is constant which makes it all a little faster to do, unlike the Equilibrium route.

Comment: Thanks :) No doubt I missed something but will add more as I learn!

Comment: Are there still packs of harmful wind after you've completed the main quest? Considering you have to "shout" your way trough the first time.

Comment: @Sharain Clear Skies temporarily clears a small area for you to walk through. If you just stand there the fog eventually comes back.

Comment: You also train armor while being attacked. I do not recall if taking damage in general (like the High Hrothgar method) will do so, but if you are swarmed by mobs, you will definitely get heavy or light armor experience if you wear that kind of armor.

Answer (score 2):

You could always just use flames and healing at the same time on shadowmere (poor shadowmere he's just a big ol' punching bag). Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 1):

Get your enchanting to 100 and claim the beginning perk five times, so your enchanting power is doubled.
Then choose the perk that gives you a 25 percent boost to skill enchants.  After that get four grand or black souls.  Enchant four pices of clothing that allow you to enchant with restoration cost reduction, each piece should reduce the cost of your restoration magic by 25 percent.  Make sure you have the ebony mail.
Now you'll want to perform the armor glitch.  If you don't know how to do it there is a you tube video that shows how, just search Skyrim armor glitch.  After doing the armor glitch so you are wearing all four pieces of your enchanted gear and the ebony mail, you will need to find a caged enemy.  Get close enough to the enemy and use a single handed healing hand spell.  The ebony mail will damage the enemy at the same rate your healing hand spell will heal.  Rubberband or tape down the spell button and after awhile your restoration will reach 100, but just make to press the y or triangle button occasionally to prevent your controller from turning off.  This method takes, but it is easy to do.

Comment: This wouldn't work without the exploit stacking a circlet with a falmer helmet or penitus oculatus helmet. The custom enchants would go on head, neck, chest and ring but the ebony mail is already occupying the chest slot in your method.

Answer (score 1):

Find any body of water without slaughterfish that you can easily extricate yourself from (or at least your head and hands for casting) and then emerge from the water right before drowning and heal yourself. Submerge, rinse, repeat. It's as easy as using shampoo and you don't have to travel to some remote hard to reach locale and you can start doing this immediately at first level!

Comment: Suggestion for improvement or clarification. Pools outside Dragonsreach. You can be in the pool facing the stairs with most of your head below water. When close to death, move forward up the stairs to cast.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just go up to a guard and hit him get him mad and say id rather die then go to prison, and then just let him hit you, and you just use fast healing. And to make it faster set it to Legendary but be careful because they will be strong. Hope this help's! :)

Answer (score 0):

Bring an invincible follower then go to high hrothgar courtyards go to the wind up the stairs in the back beside the big tower put your follower in the wind wait until he/she crouches and cast healing hands wait an hour if you run out of magika or just use the 100% free restoration 25% on each armour piece necklace, ring, bracers, and cuirass i found this useful because i am just trying to level everything to 100 while being level 101

Answer (score 0):

i found my self using equilibrium and healing at the same time witch cancels each other out allowing you to sit there and hold both spells for as long as you please and gain level in both areas. also keep in mind that it may appear as if its not doing anything cause your magicka and health bar eventually fade away and this is only because the two spells are canceling each other out but sense they are both active working on restoring the health you lose and magicka you are losing at the same time the game counts it as an active and/or notable spell and it adds points to those two skills at an equal rate.

if you dont already have the spell equilibrium check out this link to a youtube video with a walk through on how to obtain the spell

its a very informative video and helped me on obtaining the spell myself

Comment: Suggested improvement: Mention you should set difficulty to novice so you recover more health than you take away. If you bump it up a bit, even just to apprentice, the equilibrium will kill you after a little while.

Answer (score 0):

- There is a way of doing it. One of the similar thing I did is mentioned here.

  - standing infront of fire and cast fast healing.
- Another way is do the Jurgen Windcaller quest and you will encounter the place where you will step on stones that will burn you and you can cast the fast healing spell.
  This will take about an hour to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found another nice way to do it, for if you do the thieves guild. Spot of a spoiler alert! Anywho once you get to a place called the twilight sepulcher you will enter a room that has a bunch of brazier type fires that will cause you to lose continuous health until you are far enough away from them. Closer you get the more health you lose. Get just close to enough to lose health at a steady rate, then slap on healing and away you go!

Answer (score 0):

i walked into a trap the draugr tripped  swinging blades do a decent amount of damage and used healing dual cast  if you have a disease immunity necklace this is helpful unless you have a cure disease potion  it took awhile to level up to 100 but i didn't start at 15

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.
Atronach stone.
Step 2.
Go to shack just up the road from rorickstead and let the skeevers attack you while constantly healing, atronach ability will absorb diseases and convert it into magica.
Step 3.
Forgive my spelling.
Step 4.
If you contract a disease from skeevers use the shrine of akatosh on top of the hill to cure it.rinse and repeat.
Step 5.
Forgive my gramma.lol