# Are stacked one-handed damage perks additive or multiplicative?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The One-Handed perk tree contains Armsman:

- Armsman (One-Handed weapons do 20/40/60/80/100% more damage)

And the Stealth perk tree contains two perks which can modify one-handed damage:

- Backstab (Sneak attacks with one-handed weapons now do 6x damage)
- Assassin's Blade (Sneak attacks with daggers now do a total of 15x normal damage)

Are the effects of Armsman and Backstab/Assassin's Blade additive or multiplicative?

For example,
let's say I have the rank 5 Armsman perk and a dagger which inflicts X base damage.  My dagger should now inflict 2X damage: `(X + X*100%)`.

Now I acquire the Backstab perk.  When backstabbing, will my dagger inflict:

- 7X  damage (`6X + X*100%`; perks stack additively)

or

- 12X damage ( `(X + X*100%)*6`; perks stack multiplicatively)

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplicatively. (Otherwise, it would take 5 ranks to increase dagger sneak attack damage from 15x to 16x.)

First off, [this is the damage formula](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Weapons#Overview):

```
displayed damage = (base damage + item quality) * (1 + 0.4 * skill/100) *
                   (1 + perk effects) * (1 + item effects)
```

and for sneak attacks, [most damage except that from poison or enchantments should be multiplied](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sneak#Skill_Usage).

So assuming the no-ranks-in-Armsman, non-sneaking attack is `x`, then it breaks down like so for one-handed weapons:

```
+--------------+-----------+-----------+
|              | armsman 0 | armsman 5 |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| regular      |     x     |    2x     |
| sword sneak  |    6x     |   12x     |
| dagger sneak |   15x     |   30x     |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: And add Dark Brotherhood gloves for 12x/24x/30x/60x :)