# Where can I train one handed weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know Vilkas trains two-handed weapons. Who's the equivalent of Vilkas for one-handed weapons?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Whiterun, you can meet a guy called Amren, who will happily train you in one-handed combat at a Journeyman level for a fee.

Athis, a member of the Companions, also in Whiterun, will train you at an Expert level.

Burguk of Dushnikh Yal will train you at a Master level. You can find him in The Reach.

Source (for this and other trainers): [Skyrim guide](http://www.nowgamer.com/cheats/skyrim-cheats/1127545/skyrim_guide_class_and_skill_trainer_locations.html)

Comment: So the equivalent of Vilkas, the master two-handed trainer, is Burguk. I don't believe he'll train you unless you're an Orc or Blood-Kin (do a quest for him or for the stronghold southwest of Riften)

Comment: @agf I can't confirm that as I've only just met Amren in my game - do you have a source for that? I imagine there must be an alternative to him then?

Comment: I can confirm what agf says - you just need to do a quest for an orc (any orc) to be granted entry. Brawling may work also.

Comment: Nope. There are lots of trainers that require quests though, so that's nothing special.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I don't think it's quite that general. Doing a quest for the Orc smith in Markarth doesn't seem to do it. Maybe just an Orc associated with a stronghold?

Comment: @agf I did a "clear out the forsworn from x mine" for an orc miner just outside of Markarth, and he said he'd send word about me. So maybe not the smiths in Markarth, but any orc in one of the smaller settlements? There aren't all that many orcs about...

Answer (score 6):

The best way to get one-handed for free to is:

- First finish the companions quest.

Then you can take anyone in the companion "guild" as a companion. This means that you can train 5 levels of a skill per "major level" and take your money back by talking to your companion and saying: "I need to trade something."

You will therefore find your money.

Comment: Neat trick, heh

Answer (score -2):

You can just kill a bunch of bandits then use the Raise Zombie spell and kill them again.