# Which arcane enchanter is closest to a fast travel point?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I find myself using Azura's Star every time it is full to level up enchanting. Currently, I am using the arcane enchanter in Dragonsreach which is quite a walk. What is the closest arcane enchanter to a fast travel drop point? Are there any in the open world so I don't need to enter/exit the area every time?

Comment: I found one just yesterday out in the open in some bandit camp I will try to find it again and post the name and location here. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh that would be boss if you could fast travel to it. No pressure but... HURRY UP!   (I am a very impatient man)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I like to use the arcane enchanter in [Drelas' Cottage](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Drelas%27_Cottage).  Its easy to fast travel to and has both an enchanter and alchemy station.  The only draw back is that you do need to cross a loading boundary and that the owner is a rather high level mage that does not take kindly to strangers.

Here is the location on the map:
[image]

**update**

If you are playing Skyrim on steam, there is a nice mod in the workshop that adds a fast travel icon on the world map for every player owned house.

Comment: Given the 'Cleared' status on your map, I guess it would be more correct to say "the owner *was* a rather high level mage". :)

Comment: he hasn't respawned in my game yet, and since he's a named character I doubt he'll respawn

Comment: If you prefer an easier to "clear" one that is accessible right from the start, locate Anise's Cabin, just on the other side of the river near Riverwood (the first town you encounter). There's a trapdoor with a secret basement that has an Alchemy table and Enchanter. The fast travel point puts you right outside the house.

Comment: One other benefit/drawback, depending on how you look at it, is that dragons love the area. I don't know whether you're affected if you go straight for the cabin after quick travel, though.

Comment: @Christopher more like "the _former_ owner _was_ a rather high level mage"..

Comment: @Jason Nice one - though since the reader may not yet have killed said mage, it would be even more correct to say "the owner _will have been_ a rather high level mage"

Comment: WARNING: Do not attempt to retrieve ingredients and other crafting items from your follower after you've entered because they won't let you because you're trespassing.

Answer (score 6):

The fastest one to travel to that I know of is in [Mistveil Keep](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mistveil_Keep), in Riften. There is an arcane enchanter just inside, in the first room on the left.

Answer (score 6):

Found one really close to fast travel point, no fight and no loading screen.

It's a place called Sacellum of Boethiah (got there following quest lead actually) here it is on world map: (click for full image)

[image: Sacellum of Boethiah location]

Here is the enchanter in a tent up some stairs: (click for full image)

[image: Sacellum of Boethiah enchanter]

And here is the enchanter location in local map: (click for full image)

[image: enchanter exact location]

Comment: Not to mention its adjacency to an Alchemy Lab. One should probably not piss off the cultists.

Comment: @NiteCyper yeah, think I killed them all but it wasn't easy.

Comment: A big downside to this place is that at least one of the Boethiah cultists is annoying as hell. He stands beside me and won't stop yammering "A well placed word or a well placed dagger, both can achieve equal purposes" or "Do you wish to test yourself against me?" I think that the cultists and the priestess respawn, so it should be fine to kill them. The quest gotten by talking to the priestess is gotten anyway, and in a way that is probably cooler than if you just talked to her. The downside to that is the loss of a back-up source of (black) souls.

Comment: Another upside to killing the cultists is that you get to use their corpses as a portable items container to help sort gear for enchanting.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps not the fastest, but very convenient because it's very close to a marketplace and some player-owned storage containers, is the one in [Honeyside](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Honeyside) after you've bought the [upgrade](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Honeyside#Costs_and_Upgrades).

The house is just a short walk from the entrance to [Riften](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Riften), and the [Enchanter](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arcane_Enchanters) is just downstairs.  If you're [Thane of the Rift](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thane_of_the_Rift), you've also got your handy-dandy [Housecarl](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers#Housecarls), [Iona](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Iona), available if you need help carrying stuff.  And, if you're also inclined to do some [Alchemy](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy), you can buy another upgrade for the house that puts an [Alchemy Lab](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy_Labs) right in the next room.

Like I said, it may not be the absolute fastest but, I find it fairly convenient.  It's the one I personally prefer to use.

NOTE:  The link for "Enchanter" above has a list of all the Arcane Enchanters in Skyrim.

Comment: +1 for the link but.. Is honeyside the purchasable house in riften? If so, I am not interested. Earning the money required would take longer than walking the length and breadth of Windhelm a hundred times. I am looking for ways to speed up my leveling.

Comment: @Christopher Honeyside is the purchaseable house in Riften.  If you don't mind using some bug exploits to speed up your leveling, check out my thread here:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47219/whats-the-quickest-cheapest-way-to-power-level-up-to-15  The cost to purchase (including Alchemy Lab) is only 9,000.  This should not be very difficult to obtain, even for lower-level characters.  (When you think about it, it just *seems* hard.)  If you're really desperate, you can always go chop wood.

Comment: I know a lot of people are happy hacking their way to unlimited money and power and I completely understand there desires. I for one prefer to cohere to the mechanics of the game as it is intended by the developers to get the most of my gaming experience. Also, I am on the PS3 so many of these hacks are not available to me. The Oghma Infinium glitch for example is not available to PS3 users. Whilst 9,000 gold may not seem like much to you it constitutes several hours of dedicated, legitimate game-play for my character which goes against the reason for my question.

Comment: I don't know about you, but after ~42 hours of gameplay, I have gotten over 70k. (If you think Honeyside is expensive, see the house at solitude). I always have more goods than I can sell. I have at least 20k or so of dragon bones/scales saved up as well.

Comment: @user606723 which is still a fair way of the gold trophy for 100k gold at any one time. Plus I can guarantee you that my character after 32hrs is more powerful and better equipped than your own (nearing max possibly deadric armor at lvl 32 and dealing 88 dmg dual weilding with two enchanted daedric war axes) because I spend my gold and am not willing to chop wood for hours on end when I could be playing the game. Definitely not the answer(s) I am looking for.

Comment: @Christopher I've not used any glitches to gain my gold, and still found 9k fairly simple to obtain when my character was only around level 40.  The Oghma Infinium glitch *is* still available for PS3, but it only works on bookshelves.  I've done this myself within the past week on a fully-updated system.

Comment: @Christopher You can earn gold ridiculously fast via enchanting and alchemy. I'm afraid to brew potions now because they're hard to sell without feeling cheated. Enchanting is easier: raid a Dwemer ruin, buy/smith weapons, enchant. Marriage gives you 100 gold/day. A set of 3 Dragon Bones and Scales sells for 1800-4200 gold. Also, you can buy Honeyside for 5000 rather than 8000 if you don't have 8000. You don't need to break immersion; gold is easy after early game. (Also, "max" equipment requires 100 enchanting, alchemy and smithing. You're getting gold anyway if you're leveling enchanting.)

Comment: Erm, sorry, that should read 590—1365 gold for selling off a dragon's skeleton.

Comment: Iszi - Thats strange, I tried it several times at several different bookshelves. It always broke the bookshelf. Assumed it had been patched but perhaps I was doing it wrong. @Bryan -yeah between selling enchant dragon scale armour and transmuting ore and enchanting jewellery I can make 9k pretty easily. But I am working towards the 100k gold trophy while trying to keep my save file size down for this character build (ps3 lag)

Comment: @Christopher If you disable all autosave options, it will resolve the lag mostly.  At least, the game shouldn't crash on you near as much.

Comment: @Iszi - yeah thanks mate. Wish I knew about that one a few months ago. I have three characters each around lvl 40 with +10mb save files. The autosave trick helps but it only goes so far at that stage.  Does yours crash a lot? I have not had a single crash; just crippling lag and artefacts.

Comment: @Christopher I still have an occasional crash now and then, but that's been rare since I disabled autosave.  Lag still happens, but usually clears up after a bit.  When in doubt, save and reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I find Orphan Rock just southeast of Riverwood is the fastest Arcane Enchanter. It's out in the open, and there's no loading required to reach it or tough characters surrounding it.

Comment: That location doesn't spawn until you're some way into the quest starting at the big tree in Whiterun.

Answer (score 2):

In Windhelm. There is an Arcane Enchanter outside behind Niranye near the Blacksmith forge on the west side of the city.