# How can I quickly reduce the magicka costs of Alteration spells?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I found a Spell Tome book: "Telekinesis", in a dungeon and I think it is a Adept or Expert level spell and it takes around 189 Magicka per second. I can only use that spell for like 7/10's of a second with my Magicka completely full on the account with the most Magicka (around 220 or something).

**How do I get it so that I can use Telekenesis for at least 15 seconds?** Although I have thought of getting the Adept or Expert perk for Alteration that makes it cost half as much Magicka, I think it would still not take long at all to completely run out of Magicka. Also, I have thought of finding an Alteration trainer, but I can not seem to find one.

Comment: My bad. When i asked this i wasn't really paying attention to the time i want to use Telekenesis for. 15 seconds is a long time, so i want to use Telekenesis for atleast 5-8 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

One of the most effective ways to reduce your magicka costs is by wearing armour with the Fortify Alteration enchantment. Multiple pieces stack- you can wear armor, a ring, an amulet and a helmet with the enchantment on it. With a high enough enchanting you can get -25% on each and cast that school for free.

Comment: You can also wear a falmer helmet, in addition to any other helmet/crown/circlet/hood.  This allows you to cast alteration spells for free if you can just get up to a 20% reduction in spell cost via fortify alteration enchantments on all five items (ring/necklace/armor/head/Falmer Helmet).  

Even if you can't yet get to 20% per item, it will still reduce your magicka cost significantly, with the extra enchantment added by the Falmer Helmet.

Comment: So you can wear a Falmer Helmet on top of anything else?

Comment: Yes, you can wear a Falmer Helmet in addition to any other head slot armor.  This gives you the chance to get a little extra armor, and double the number enchantments from the head slot.

Comment: Oh and what mineral do you use to improve a Falmer Helmet?

Answer (score 5):

When I was training Alteration, I always used the Flesh spells like Oak Flesh and Ebony Flesh.  The higher the level the quicker it raises Alteration. I usually just stayed by Slaughterfish on the edge of the water while continuously casting the spell.  This seemed to get it up pretty quickly.  Otherwise I know there is a Alteration trainer in the College in Winterhold, I think his name was Tolfdir or something similar.

Comment: Whoa there is Ebony Flesh? All those kinds of spells I've seen was Oakflesh Stoneflesh and Ironflesh.

Comment: @soulreaper  Yes there is here is a list of all the Alteration spells: [Mage Armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mage_Armor#Mage_Armor)  I believe Ebony Flesh can be bought from Tolfdir in Winterhold.

Comment: If you can't find the Ebonyflesh spell, you probably need to continue to raise the level of your alteration skill.  More powerful spells are only available once you have raised your skill level in that school of magic.

Comment: Do you have to be a certain level to buy Ebony Flesh from Tolfdir?

Comment: @soulreaper Yes, you have to be level 70 Alteration in order to get Ebony Flesh from Tolfdir.

Answer (score 2):

Using Detect Life in crowded places is a pretty easy way to level it up. But if you want some sweet details check out this link:

[Skyrim: Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alteration#Skill_Increases)

I use that website when I need some tips, it's super useful!

Comment: Poop. I have to wait until I get home. lol. i'm at school right now.

Comment: Lol, I'm at work XD

Comment: Please don't direct a user to just find the information somewhere else.  That's the whole point of what we do here.  Summarize the information here, so that your answer can stand on it's own in case that website ever goes down.

Comment: I see your point and I will be sure to follow that convention in the future, thank you. But I believe your logic is flawed about the other website going down. If I solely provided information here and THIS site went down, the user would be left in the dark. In this case I have at least provided two sites of information for further redundancy.