# How to quickly train Block in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My level 45 character has dragon armor but my Block skill is lagging behind (53 at the moment). How can I train it quickly?

Answer (score 11):

Get the very best shield you can (along with your best armor, etc).  Don't forget enchantments.  Block a hit from a giant.  Heal.  Repeat.  :D

If you can suppress a dragon's breath weapon long enough to make him fight you in melee, blocking a strong dragon for a while will work too.  The problem with using a dragon is that if you have a healing spell in your right hand, you're not hitting for magicka damage or with anti-magicka poison, so they'll eventually breath weapon you again.  Giants are easier if you can survive a hit.

Either method is likely to train your Restoration too, assuming you're healing with spells and not potions.

Answer (score 0):

Skeevers are the best imo have a shield in one hand and a restoration spell in the other with the warrior stone and you sit there until you get bored yes it does take longer but this way you have nearly no risk of dying and losing all the progress you have made.