# What's a quick way to level conjuration?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My conjuration is level 26 and I can't seem to figure out a quick way to level it. What's the quickest/most effective way to level it up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I level up a spell faster by casting often or by casting longer?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34900/do-i-level-up-a-spell-faster-by-casting-often-or-by-casting-longer)

Comment: When you first start the game and come out of the first cave where the dragon fly's over you their is a blessing stone near by that lets your magic skills level up faster. I have found to have a summon spell in one hand and bound weapon in the other. Within about 2 hours or so my conjuration was in the 50's.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [*Good list of way to train all your skills* on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/medbn/good_list_of_way_to_train_all_your_skills/)

> **Conjuration**
>
> - Buy the bound sword
> - Find slaughterfish
> - Stand at the edge of water so slaughterfish can't attack you, and so    that you'll still be in combat
> - Cast bound sword (don't dual sword it), sheath your weapon and       repeat.
>
> You can get the Apprentice Conjuration magic perk to make this process
>   go by faster. This process is so quick you can have 100 conjuration in
>   little over 1 and a half hour. OR repeatedly cast soul trap on any
>   dead creature.

Comment: I found these techniques to work the best for quick conjuration leveling.

Comment: I guess this works if you don't actually want to _play_ the game..

Comment: True that snailer. Is useful if you want a perk and you're 1 or 2 skillpoints off the required amount :)

Comment: So casting summon spells without enemies being near does not level your Conjuration?

Because I always cast these spells before I get into combat, as that is the only logical way to play.

Comment: Snailer, literally anyone asking about the fastest way to level something doesn't care about "playing" the game.

Comment: it is actually faster to cast a sword in each hand than to cast it in just one. Dual casting(so you get one sword in one hand that lasts twice as long) does not get extra XP. You just need a slight offset in casting time between hands. Then you get double XP for casting the spell twice.

Answer (score 15):

Kill a weak monster (skeever) and use soul trap on it about five times, if not six then wait for one hour to regenerate magica

Comment: For the downvoters, this *does* work.

Comment: As an added bonus you level enchanting too! (if you have soul gems)

Answer (score 9):

Your conjuration skill does not increase by conjuring anything *out of combat*, it only increases while you' in combat with something or someone. Conjuring up a creature and a weapon, and then entering combat does level up your conjuration skill.

So, try to just conjure a creature and use a bound weapon in all fights, this will level up your conjuration skill relatively quickly.

You can also cast Soultrap on dead enemies, so you could put on a lot of magicka regeneration gear and continuously cast Soultrap on dead enemies to level up the skill. Alternatively, cast it until you run out of magicka and wait an hour (using the wait feature) and repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the first straight forward answer to when you actually get the experience.
But do you just get it at creation, or latter when you encounter enemies? But both times just the one set amount? Or do you get experience relative to the length of time in combat with a summon?

Answer (score 8):

I use a Bound Sword as my *only* weapon, and my conjuration is around 40 at level 11. I would suggest using Bound Items in combat.

Answer (score 3):

In the lower conjuration-levels (around 20) the Soultrap spell gives nearly 1 level of Conjuration per use.

Comment: Soultrapping small animals is a quick way indeed.

Comment: Definitely going to try this.

Answer (score 2):

You can also summon a creature, and then attack it with a bound weapon. 
After a while the summon will start fighting back, and you'll get experience.

It may be a bit cheesy, but it works and it can be done everywhere!

Answer (score 2):

Least "boring" way I've found: keep two spells handy while exploring, something like Conjure Flame Atronach and Soul Trap, or Bound Sword and Soul Trap. Soul trap everything when you get the magicka, even while not in combat, even your companion (I don't know how many times Lydia's threatened to kill me) as you explore--animals, dead bodies, etc. Conjure Atronach or Sword to deal with low level baddies you are likely to encounter. Switch to a favorite damage dealing spell or weapon for dragons, giants, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've noticed conjuration goes up by having a conjured creature out, but maybe only when you're actually fighting something.

Answer (score 1):

While soul trapping for easy conjuration skills think about spending your hard earned cash on as many empty soul gems as you can buy and level your enchanting skill while your at it.

You can also use the invisible chest in Dawnstar to find soul gems for free

Answer (score 0):

Conjuration does only level up in combat, however you can summon a creature, such as an atronach, then summon a bound weapon and start beating on it. At about half health it will turn on you and you will get some skill ups for being in combat.

Answer (score 0):

Summon atronach, make it attack you, hide from attacks, and constantly cast a bound weapon. Best to hot key it for pc users and just switch to a new spell and back to bound weapon. Happy leveling